# CSS - How to align container box in the same line?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I'm trying to make my progress bar go horizontal in the same line but it doesn't work ,
I will post here a picture of how it should be and the result that I got :

[image]

and this is what i tried to do  :

```css
.skills-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

I tried a couple of things but still, it doesn't work,
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: We need more information, like the HTML code for example. Also, you just uploaded one image but would be nice to have the end result vs what you got.

Comment: Share your code for better understanding of the issue